# Pass object value out of event listener scope

Tags: javascript, event-handling

How can I pass the object value out of my event listener scope?

```
addbtn.onclick = function(){
    const fName = firstName.value;
    const lName = lastName.value;
    const trSubject = trainerSubject.value;

    let trainer = {
        fName,
        lName,
        trSubject
    };
};
```

Comment: Pass where? What code do you expect to use the object value? How do you ensure that it runs only after the button has been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code to have `trainer` as a global variable and then set its values using your eventListener
And also, your `trainer` variable has a list of elements and is not in a key, value pair format, so I will assume you meant an array and fix that for you.

```
let trainer = [];
addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const fName = firstName.value;
    const lName = lastName.value;
    const trSubject = trainerSubject.value;
    trainer.push([fName, lName, trSubject]);
});
```

If you meant the `trainer` variable to be an object in the form of

```
let trainer = {
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    trSubject: ""
};
```

Then inside your event listener you can set the values of that object using `trainer.fName = fName` etc etc.